# WSL "failed to access sysfs directory"

Tags: linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use ubuntu on win10, I typed :

```
lsblk
```

result:

> failed to access sysfs directory

how can I fix it

Comment: Hi, this question probably belongs to [Super User](https://superuser.com/). `lsblk` is known to not work in WSL1 as it doesn't provide `/sys/dev/block` kernel interface. So this is expected and you can't fix it.

Comment: What is there to fix?? That command isn't supposed to work in WSL

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.